# return of NULL in SELECT query from different Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What I'm doing is trying to ORDER BY the last messages.

I'm trying to SELECT the last time that stored in the 'conversations_messages' Table as a 'message_date' row (integer), but the query returns me a NULL, instead of the biggest time.

here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT conversations.id, conversations.subject, conversations.sender,
        MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) AS 'last_reply',
        MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_users.last_view AS 'unread'
        FROM conversations
        LEFT JOIN conversations_messages ON conversations.id=conversations_messages.message_id
        INNER JOIN conversations_users ON conversations.id=conversations_users.conversation_id
        WHERE conversations_users.user_id=$user_id AND conversations_users.deleted=0
        GROUP BY conversations.id
        ORDER BY 'last_reply' DESC
```

**The query is working well apart from the 'last_reply' that returned as NULL - and that is my problem.**

I tried to solve the problem by splitting the query into two queries, my new query was :

```
SELECT MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) AS 'last_reply',
       MAX(conversations_messages.message_date) > conversations_users.last_view AS 'unread'
              FROM conversations_messages
              LEFT JOIN conversations ON conversations_messages.message_id=conversations.id
              INNER JOIN conversations_users ON conversations_messages.conversation_id=conversations_users.conversation_id
              WHERE conversations_messages.conversation_id = $id
```

This query is working well and returning the right value, but I need to merge it into the first query somehow. I'd tried for some hours but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? Which one is it?

Comment: use the alias and the position of your table data from which you fetch the record

Comment: Get the conversation id for which you got result from second query and try to check this in Conversations table, I am sure there will be no result for the same and hence showing null value for the first query.